# React Native / Expo: Push notifications for standalone Apps

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I can't find the answer to this question anywhere in the documentation.

- Can I send push notifications to standalone (not detached) apps using the exponentPushToken[xxxxx] token? Maybe using expo's push service URL (https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send)?
- or, for standalone apps, the only way to do it is using the "real" device token?

Note: I'm not detaching the App.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to answer this question by generating standalone iOS app from the command line running:

```
exp build:ios
```

Then installed the IPA file on my iOS device using TestFlight, sent a push notification to the "exponentPushToken[xxxxx]" of my physical device  through the Expo service: `https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send` and the notification arrived perfectly.